# Непонятный переброс

Tags: dns, iis, mikrotik

Есть два IIS сервера:

1. 1-й старый,
2. 2-й новый,

так же есть в сети маршрутизатор Mikrotik который перенаправляет внешние запросы с белого IP, во внутреннюю сеть, для 80 и 443 явно указан именно только 2-й сервер. Так же есть зарегистрированный хостинг с DNS зонами. Есть сайт (Все названия будут с рокировкой, то есть, примерами) wikipedia.com, у неё есть поддомен на втором сервере `microsoft.wikipedia.com` и есть так же на Mikrotik проброс портов на этот же сайт, но только в виде порта `wikipedia.com:8000`. Сайт с портом проброшенным на "мир" в Mikrotik находится на 1-ом сервере, в хостинге есть зарегистрированный `microsoft.wikipedia.com` и этот же поддомен указан на 2-ом сервере, если обращаться к сайту по HTTP, то он пробрасывает сразу на `wikipedia.com:8000`, а если обращаться по HTTPS, то он отлично заходит на `microsoft.wikipedia.com`. В настройках ISS и/или web.config никаких переадресаций нет. Даже если в Mikrotik выключить проброс портов на 8000-й порт, то сайт по HTTP всё равно идёт и пробует стучаться на старое место, с HTTPS такого нет. В нашей организации HTTP важен для рабочих внутренних процессов, потому это просто необходимо. Куда смотреть и что ещё надо предоставить?